# Django 1.6 - Nested Pagination

Tags: python, django, pagination

I have 2 variables: a queryset(shops) and a simple list(inventory).
My goal is to paginate trough all shops but at the same time, have the possibility to look trough the inventory of each and every shop. The pagination of the inventory should not affect the pagination of the shops. My problem is that both paginations start at the same page, but then affect each other. For example: shops 1of2 and inventory 1of3 -> shops2of2 and inventory 2of3(it should stay at 1of3).

my view:

```
def some_function(request):
shops = ... #queryset
inventory = ... #list

paginator1 = Paginator(shops, 2)
page1 = request.GET.get('page')
try:
    shops = paginator1.page(page1)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    shops = paginator1.page(1)
except EmptyPage:
    shops = paginator1.page(paginator1.num_pages)

paginator2 = Paginator(inventory, 2)
page2 = request.GET.get('page')
try:
    inventory = paginator2.page(page2)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    inventory = paginator2.page(1)
except EmptyPage:
    inventory = paginator2.page(paginator2.num_pages)
```

one part of my template:

```
   <div class="pagination">
   <span class="step-links">
    {% if shops.has_previous %}
        <a href="?page={{ shops.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
    {% endif %}

    <span class="current">
        Page {{ shops.number }} of {{ shops.paginator.num_pages }}.
    </span>

    {% if shops.has_next %}
        <a href="?page={{ shops.next_page_number }}">next</a>
    {% endif %}
</span>
```

Bboth paginations work fine on their own.
I tried endless pagination, but it didn't work out.
I also tried to change 'page' in request.GET.get('page') to 'page1' and 'page2'.

Thanks for your help